# Show/Hide status bar in only one ViewController, objective C, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

I want status bar to show up in viewWillAppear() and disappear in viewWillDisappear() of my ViewController

I was using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
```

but it is deprecated in iOS 9.0

I am using

```
UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
```

in swift, but in objective C this is readonly value...

prefersStatusBarHidden also does not work for me, because I need to hide status bar in viewWillDisappear() function

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Great question! I've been struggling with these too recently!

Comment: You can try to add the key "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" with value "NO" in the info.plist, also call the func setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() if need.

Comment: I have "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance - NO " in the info.plist,  I need the translate  "UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false" swift code to objective C

Answer (score 5):

For each view controller you want to change the visibility of the status bar you need to override `prefersStatusBarHidden`. For this to *actually* work though, you must add the following key/value in your project's `Info.plist`:

**Key:**
`View controller-based status bar appearance`

**Value:** `YES`

---

To control the visibility of the status bar in `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` you can do:

```
var statusBarHidden = false

override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    statusBarHidden = false
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override func viewWillDisappear() {
    super.viewWillDisappear()
    statusBarHidden = true
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return statusBarHidden
}
```

Comment: Yes it will work definitely, but I want to avoid overriding this method in each view controller

 and I know it is possible in swift and suppose that would be possible in objective C too, but cannot find the correct function

Comment: To avoid overriding this method in each view controller, you can subclass UIViewController with these methods and use the subclass where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3,

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        return true
    }
```

and add `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
```

Comment: This is the right answer! But I did not need the statement in `viewDidLoad()`. It works without it.

Comment: ```self.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true``` is the right for answer for modal view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Write example for Objective-C (The same code for SWIFT already wrote by @dennykim)

1. Create property for BOOL

   ```
   @property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL statusBarHidden;
   ```
2. Set in info.plist **View controller-based status bar appearance** == **YES**
3. Go to ViewController and write the next code:

   ```
   -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];

       self.statusBarHidden = TRUE;
       [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
   }

   -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
       [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

       self.statusBarHidden = FALSE;
       [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
   }

   - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
       return self.statusBarHidden;
   }
   ```